# Manageability vs. Maintainability

Tags: maintainability

What is the difference between manageability and maintainability?

I have read a few definitions for [maintainability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability#Software_engineering) and [manageability](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/14415/en/) but they sound pretty similar to me...

Comment: I think this is a better fit for the _Programmers_ site, as it is a theoretical question. However, to be sure, it is worth looking at the on-topic guidelines for that site. I think it is insufficiently code-oriented for _Stack Overflow_.

Answer (score 2):

### Manageability relates to the operation of a system.

Typically this is a greater consideration for a service rather than a desktop or mobile application, although those have manageability concerns as well (do they update themselves, can they be managed with System Center, Casper, MDM, etc).

For a service, there is a wider variety of concerns:

- Cost/complexity/reliability of upgrades and downgrades
- Integration with existing monitoring systems, e.g. Splunk, New Relic, etc.
- Compatibility with other applications in a hosted environment
- Suitability for cloud hosting (e.g. AWS, Azure)

### Maintainability relates to changes to the system itself.

Specifically, it's typically used to refer to the ease and reliability of making code changes. Factors that can influence this include:

- Automated test coverage / CI
- Ease/repeatability of dev environment setup
- Initial architecture/design
- Implementation quality
- Platform/language/IDE capabilities

Answer (score 1):

> Maintainability—"The ease with which a software system or component
>   can be modified to correct faults, improve performance, or other
>   attributes, or adapt to a changed environment" [IEEE 1990].
>
> Manageability—How efficiently and easily a software system can be
>   monitored and maintained to keep the system performing, secure, and
>   running smoothly.

What I get from this is that maintainability is when adding features, fixing bugs, or making enhancements can be easily done. Manageability on the other hand is the ability to monitor and keep a secure system when its up.

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896744.aspx](http://http:/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896744.aspx)